# Deploy console based python application using google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I deploy the console based python application in google app engine?

here is my sample code:

```
import webapp2
 currencies = {
 "Rupee":"(Indian Rupee)",
 "Real":"(Brazilian Real)",
 "Dollar":"(US Dollar)",
 "Euro":"(Euro)",
 "Pound":"(Great Britain Pound)"
 }
 def real_to_dollar():
    user_value = raw_input("How many rupee?")
    ammount = 43
    conversion = ammount / 3.59
     print str(user_value) + " rupee is equal to " + str(conversion)+pound."

print "Welcome to currency converter."
print "Supported currencies:"
for currency in currencies:
   print currency + " " + currencies[currency]
#user_choice1 = raw_input("Convert: ")
#user_choice2 = raw_input("To: ")
user_choice1 ="Real"
user_choice2 ="Dollar"
if user_choice1 == "Real" and user_choice2 == "Dollar":
   real_to_dollar() 
elif user_choice1 == "Dollar" and user_choice2 == "Real":
    dollar_to_real()
else:
  print "Enter valid one!!"
```

While using runtime values,log file shows EOF error.so I give static values.After that there is no error in log file.
now,my question is how can I view the output in google app engine?
Or whether there is any command to run it in command prompt??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could run this in Google AppEngine, but what you are trying to do is not really suited for running there. Instead, you can install the Python Runtime on your PC (i am assuming its a Windows PC). Download the installer from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/

Once installed, in your command prompt you can run your program. Save the code you wrote to a file e.g currency.py and run it with the python interpreter.

```
C:\> python currency.py
```

Comment: :so..Will this can't be deployed using google app engine??

Comment: Not the way you have written it. Google AppEngine is for Web Applications. There is no 'console' to interact with the user. You will have to re-write this is a web application where user input is coming in as an HTTP Request and your output is actually a HTTP Response. If you are interested in running this in AppEngine start with this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

And then once get that follow this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction
This app is very similar to what you are trying to do.